# Lost Two Mouse Functions

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I recently did a system restore on my laptop and have, it seems, lost two mouse functions as a result. The two to which I am refering are, the scrolling feature and the zoom feature. I have searched google for a solution, but all rely things which I have no access to. More specifically, most suggest going to "mouse and touchpad settings," and then click on "additional mouse options." However, if you refer to the pictures [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-pinch-zoom-gesture-on-windows-laptops/), I am missing the following tabs: Wheel, Hardware, and Device Setting.

PS It seems that i have lost all functions except its "ordinary" mouse capability.

Comment: So is your "mouse" an actual mouse or a touchpad?

Comment: Yes, it is a touchpad.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Have you reinstalled the drivers related to your touchpad?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, and I believe the drivers have been reinstalled. I went to Device Manager, right clicked on ASUS Touchpad, and clicked Update Driver Software. After trying to update, it said that the best software was already installed.

Comment: I would suggest you verify you have the latest BIOS and install drivers from the manufacturer, rather than let Windows pick.